# can't understand why the app crash "attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]"

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to the Firebase Storage, while trying to upload the data, my application crashes.
This is the error I get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
```

This is my code (After the user clicks the upload button, Calling uploadPostImage to upload it to the Firebase Storage):

```
@objc func addBtnTapped(){
    //Checking if the user chose photo, so user's won't upload photos with the placeholder image.
    if userChoseImage == true{
        let userID : String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!
        let postUUID = UUID().uuidString
        guard let postTitle = self.titleTextField.text else { return }
        uploadPostImage { url in
            self.ref.child("posts").child(postUUID).setValue(["title": postTitle,"imageUrl": "http://www.test.com" ,"numberOfLikes": 0, "numberOfDislikes": 0, "postCreator": userID])
        }

    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: "Please chose image by clicking on the image placeholder photo.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is uploadPostImage:

```
   func uploadPostImage(completion: @escaping((_ url: String?)->())){

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    guard let uploadData = self.postImage.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else { return }

    let metaData = StorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

    //I think the crash happens here
    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metaData) { metaData, error in
        if error == nil && metaData != nil{
            if let url = metaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                completion(url)
            }else{
                completion(nil)
            }
        }else{
        }
    }

}
```

I thought, maybe the URL I get is nil, but I tried to just throw a url in there, but it still crashes, I set a breakpoint in the uploadPostImage, but nothing seems to be nil.
I can't really figure out what's happening.

Comment: this will still be a problem also `if let url = metaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{` you need to change it